# Argument 1 passed to App\Mail\OrderPlaced::__construct()

Tags: php, laravel, email

I want to display the information of an order in a placed.plade.php balde but it gives me error: `Argument 1 passed to App\Mail\OrderPlaced::__construct() must be an instance of App\Mail\ App\Order, null given, called in D:\wamp\www\aswakt\routes\web.php` on line 77
even I pass an argument in the model constructor OrderPlaced.php.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/mailable', function(){
    $order = App\Order::find(1);
    return new App\Mail\OrderPlaced($order);
});
```

**OrderPlaced.php**

```
public $order;
public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->to($this->order->billing_email,$this->order->billing_name)
                    ->bcc('another@another.com')
                    ->subject('Order for aswak tinghir ')  
                    ->markdown('emails.orders.placed');
    }
```

**placed.blade.php**

```
**Order ID:** {{ $order->id }}

**Order Email:** {{ $order->billing_email }}

**Order Name:** {{ $order->billing_name }}

**Order Total:** ${{ round($order->billing_total / 100, 2) }}
```

Comment: `App\Mail\App\Order`? Did you use `use App\Order` in your `OrderPlaced.php`?

Comment: @brombeer thx for u answer, yes i add `use App\Order` in model `OrderPlaced.php`

Comment: "_null given_" ... can you validate that there actually is an order with id=1? `dd($order);`

Comment: Is your Order not a model? App\Models\Order ???

Comment: @brombeer `dd($order)` give me `null`

Comment: Exactly, that's what the error is telling you.

Comment: @brombeer thx its solved i dont have a order when `id = 1` i try `id=9` its work will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes because the parameter `$order` you are passing at `return new App\Mail\OrderPlaced($order);` is null. This comes because there is no order with `id = 1` found in your `orders` table.